# Detecting a clustering matrix via the SVD

Tags: graph-theory, svd

Is there any easy way to detect using the SVD that a matrix $A$ is an adjacency matrix of a graph with disjoint cliques (i.e. that $A$ is a clustering matrix?). Up to a reordering of columns a cluster matrix is a block diagonal matrix with blocks filled with $1$'s.

The SVD of a clustering matrix will be low rank with integer values for the singular values. But given the SVD of a matrix $A$, can we conclude that $A$ is or is not a clustering matrix?

Comment: A related question is whether one can tell it's _approximately_ such a matrix.  Imagine small number $m$ of things to be measured, the measurements being $X_1,\ldots,X_m$, and for each a number of measurements with independent errors: $X_i + \varepsilon_{ik}$, for $j=1,\ldots,n_i$.  Now suppose we don't know of any two measurements $X_i+\varepsilon_{ik}$ and $X_j+\varepsilon_{jk}$ whether $i$ and $j$ are the same or different.  So are these two measurements part of the same clique or a different one?  Further imagine that one doesn't know in advance how many cliques there are.